# Parameter is not type-compatible with formal parameter when method is called from FM

Tags: methods, abap, saprfc, function-module

A static public class method, zcl_abc=>dosomething, has an importing parameter

> it_lines type TLINE_T optional

And there is a FM called zfm_dosame. It has a parameter

> TABLES    IT_LINES TYPE  TLINE_T OPTIONAL

zfm_dosame calls zcl_abc=>dosomething and tries to pass it_lines to it_lines. However, syntax error:

> IT_LINES is not type-compatible with formal parameter IT_LINES.

This error drives me crazy. I have no idea how come... Please help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The TABLES part of a function interface creates internal tables with header line at runtime.
So in order to pass the entire table, instead of just one work area, you should pass `IT_LINES[]` instead of `IT_LINES` to the method you're calling.

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to tell without more information like the full source code of your function module, function group, and class, but I'll take a guess: Most likely your type TLINE_T is not a global type, but is instead defined locally (and differently) in both the function group of the function module and in the class.

Try double-clicking on the type TLINE_T in both places and see where that brings you. If it brings you to a global type (which you should also be able to see in SE11) in both places, then I'm wrong and there is something else going on.

Comment: `TLINE_T` is a dictionary type, used by SAPscript functions.